# How to set Link in mail Using Grails 2.2.0

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

i am trying to set a link via grails tag.. but its just show me controller and action name

```
<g:link controller="email" action="sendpart" id="${mailObj?.to_id}">View inbox </g:link>
```

in URL it Just shows me

**`http://Demo/email/sendpart/2`**

Rather than

**`http://localhost:8080/Demo/email/sendpart/2`**

Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

Add `absolute="true"`

```
<g:link controller="email" action="sendpart" id="${mailObj?.to_id}" absolute="true">View inbox </g:link>
```

Enjoy.

Comment: Thanks For reply.. I tried this also.. but it gives me an error   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
Message
You cannot read the scheme in non-request rendering operations

Comment: Had you set your server url in config file.

Comment: If you look in your config.groovy you will see a line commented out in the production block

// TODO: grails.serverURL = "http://www.changeme.com". You need to add a similar line (setting) in whatever environment you're in (development prob). This is the value it uses when constructing a URL using absolute URLs

Answer (score 1):

Add `base` url in the [g:link](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/link.html) like

```
<g:link controller="first" action="test" base="http://localhost:8080/myApp">Click</g:link>
```